# EventBus post and subscribe in the same fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I have a fragment that makes the data synchro with a remote server, I need to send various distinct objects instances and it must run in the background so I implemented an AsyncTask per object. In this Asynctask I prepare data to be sent to a remote server through a WebService. when it receives the response, it mast post an event, that is caught by a subscriber in the same fragment. My trouble is that the first time the event is posted correctly, but in the next posts, the event multiply.

That's my code:

```
public class SincroFragment extends Fragment {

    private String uid = "";

    private DaoSession daoSession;

    private WebDatumApi webDatumApi;

    private String token;

    private int usuarioId;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;


    public SincroFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sincro, container, false);

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        daoSession = ((MDatumController)getActivity().getApplication()).getDaoSession();

        webDatumApi = ((MDatumController)getActivity().getApplication()).getApiSession();

        prefs =  getActivity().getApplication().getSharedPreferences("MDATUM_PREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        token = prefs.getString("PREF_USER_TOKEN",null);

        usuarioId = prefs.getInt("PREF_USER_LOGED",0);


        EncuestaDao encuestaDao = daoSession.getEncuestaDao();

        List<Encuesta> encuestas = encuestaDao.queryBuilder().where(EncuestaDao.Properties.Is_finished.eq(true),EncuestaDao.Properties.IsSincronized.eq(false)).list();
        for(int i = 0; i < encuestas.size() ; i ++){
            uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"-"+String.valueOf(encuestas.get(i).getId())+"-"+String.valueOf(encuestas.get(i).getUsuario());

            Encuesta encuesta = encuestas.get(i);
            encuesta.setTransaccion(uid);

            encuestaDao.update(encuesta);

            Transaccion transaccion = new Transaccion();
            transaccion.setEncuestaId(encuesta.getId());
            transaccion.setTransaccion(uid);
            try{
                daoSession.insert(transaccion);
            }catch (SQLiteConstraintException e){
                daoSession.update(transaccion);
            }

            Establecimiento establecimiento = encuestas.get(i).getEstablecimientoRelated();
            establecimiento.setTransaccion(uid);

            new EstablecimientoSynchroTask().execute(establecimiento);

        }




        return rootview;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MensajesDeEvento evento){

        switch (evento.getDispatcher()){
            case "EstablecimientoTask":
                if(evento.getEvento().equals("Success")){
                    Encuesta encuesta = getEncuestaByTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                    Encuestado  encuestado = encuesta.getEncuestadoRelated();
                    encuestado.setTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                    new EncuestadoSynchroTask().execute(encuestado);
                }
                break;
            case "EncuestadoTask":
                if(evento.getEvento().equals("Success")){
                    Encuesta encuesta = getEncuestaByTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                    Familia familia = encuesta.getFamiliaRelated();
                    if(familia != null){
                        familia.setTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                        new FamiliaSynchroTask().execute(familia);
                    }else {
                        MensajesDeEvento event =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        event.setEvento("Success");
                        event.setDispatcher("FamiliaTask");
                        event.setTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "FamiliaTask":
                if(evento.getEvento().equals("Success")){
                    Encuesta encuesta = getEncuestaByTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                    Agroquimicos agroquimico = encuesta.getAgroquimicoRelated();
                    if(agroquimico!= null){
                        agroquimico.setTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                        new AgroquimicoSynchroTask().execute(agroquimico);
                    }else{
                        MensajesDeEvento event =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        event.setEvento("Success");
                        event.setDispatcher("AgroquimicoTask");
                        event.setTransaccion(evento.getTransaccion());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "AgroquimicoTask":
                if(evento.getEvento().equals("Success")){
                    new ObtenerIdsTask().execute(evento.getTransaccion());
                }
                break;
            case "GetIdsTask":
                if(evento.getEvento().equals("Success")){
                    Encuesta encuesta = (Encuesta) evento.getObject();
                    new EncuestaSynchroTask().execute(encuesta);
                }
                break;

        }


    }

    private class EstablecimientoSynchroTask extends AsyncTask<Establecimiento,Void,Long>{

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Establecimiento... establecimientos) {

            Long id = 0L;
            final Establecimiento establecimiento = establecimientos[0];

            //Obtengo el archivo de la foto del establecimiento
            File foto                   = new File(establecimiento.getFoto());
            //preparo la parte del cuerpo del mensaje que lleva la imagen
            RequestBody reqFile         = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), foto);
            final MultipartBody.Part body     = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("foto",foto.getName(),reqFile);
            //preparo el resto de las partes del mensaje
            RequestBody nombre          = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),establecimiento.getNombre());
            RequestBody numero          = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),establecimiento.getNro());
            RequestBody posLatitud      = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),establecimiento.getPosLatitud());
            RequestBody posLongitud     = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),establecimiento.getPosLongitud());
            RequestBody regimenTenencia = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Integer.toString(establecimiento.getRegimenTenenciaId()));
            RequestBody regimenOtros    = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),establecimiento.getRegimenOtros());
            RequestBody transaccion     = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), establecimiento.getTransaccion());

            //Instancio una llamada con las partes generadas anteriormente
            Call<Establecimiento> establecimientoCall = webDatumApi.sincroEstablecimiento(
                    "Token " + token,
                    body,
                    nombre,
                    numero,
                    posLatitud,
                    posLongitud,
                    regimenTenencia,
                    regimenOtros,
                    transaccion
            );

            establecimientoCall.enqueue(new Callback<Establecimiento>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Establecimiento> call, Response<Establecimiento> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        MensajesDeEvento evento =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        evento.setEvento("Success");
                        evento.setDispatcher("EstablecimientoTask");
                        evento.setTransaccion(response.body().getTransaccion());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(evento);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Establecimiento> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            return id;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
            super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        }
    }


    private class EncuestadoSynchroTask extends AsyncTask<Encuestado,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Encuestado... encuestados) {

            Encuestado encuestado = encuestados[0];



            Call<Encuestado> encuestadoCall = webDatumApi.sincroEncuestado(
                    "Token " + token,
                    encuestado
            );

            encuestadoCall.enqueue(new Callback<Encuestado>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Encuestado> call, Response<Encuestado> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        MensajesDeEvento evento =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        evento.setEvento("Success");
                        evento.setDispatcher("EncuestadoTask");
                        evento.setTransaccion(response.body().getTransaccion());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(evento);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Encuestado> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }

    private class AgroquimicoSynchroTask extends AsyncTask<Agroquimicos, Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Agroquimicos... agroquimicos) {

            Call<Agroquimicos> agroquimicosCall = webDatumApi.sincroAgroquimico(
                    "Token " + token,
                    agroquimicos[0]
            );

            agroquimicosCall.enqueue(new Callback<Agroquimicos>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Agroquimicos> call, Response<Agroquimicos> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        MensajesDeEvento evento =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        evento.setEvento("Success");
                        evento.setDispatcher("AgroquimicoTask");
                        evento.setTransaccion(response.body().getTransaccion());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(evento);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Agroquimicos> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }

    private class FamiliaSynchroTask extends  AsyncTask<Familia,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Familia... familias) {

            Call<Familia> familiaCall = webDatumApi.sincroFamilia(
                    "Token " + token,
                    familias[0]
            );

            familiaCall.enqueue(new Callback<Familia>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Familia> call, Response<Familia> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        MensajesDeEvento evento =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        evento.setEvento("Success");
                        evento.setDispatcher("FamiliaTask");
                        evento.setTransaccion(response.body().getTransaccion());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(evento);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Familia> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }

    private class EncuestaSynchroTask extends AsyncTask<Encuesta,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Encuesta... encuestas) {

            Call<Encuesta> encuestaCall = webDatumApi.sincroEncuesta(
                    "Token " + token,
                    encuestas[0]
            );

            encuestaCall.enqueue(new Callback<Encuesta>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Encuesta> call, Response<Encuesta> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("SUCCESS","SUCCESS ENCUESTA");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Encuesta> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }



    private class ObtenerIdsTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            final String transaccion = strings[0];
            Call<IdsSincro> idsCall = webDatumApi.getIdsByTransaccion("Token "+token,strings[0]);
            idsCall.enqueue(new Callback<IdsSincro>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<IdsSincro> call, Response<IdsSincro> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        Encuesta encuesta = new Encuesta();
                        encuesta.setEstablecimientoId(response.body().getEstablecimiento());
                        encuesta.setEncuestadoId(response.body().getEncuestado());
                        encuesta.setFamiliaId(response.body().getFamilia());
                        encuesta.setAgroquimicoId(response.body().getAgroquimico());
                        encuesta.setFecha(getEncuestaByTransaccion(transaccion).getFecha());
                        encuesta.setUsuario(getEncuestaByTransaccion(transaccion).getUsuario());
                        encuesta.setTransaccion(transaccion);
                        MensajesDeEvento evento =  new MensajesDeEvento();
                        evento.setEvento("Success");
                        evento.setDispatcher("GetIdsTask");
                        evento.setTransaccion(transaccion);
                        evento.setObject(encuesta);
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(evento);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<IdsSincro> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }

    private Encuesta getEncuestaByTransaccion(String transaction){
        TransaccionDao transaccionDao = daoSession.getTransaccionDao();
        Transaccion transaccion = transaccionDao.queryBuilder().where(TransaccionDao.Properties.Transaccion.eq(transaction)).list().get(0);
        return transaccion.getEncuesta();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you switching your fragment some how? you are subscribing to the event bus in onCreateView, if that is called multiple times, you will get multiple callbacks, either subscribe in onCreate, or unsubscribe in onDestroyView

Comment: You're right, I forgot to cancel the subscription. Thank you!

Comment: Posting as answer to help the future fellas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you switching your fragment somehow? you are `subscribing` to the event bus in `onCreateView`, if that is called multiple times, you will get multiple callbacks, either subscribe in `onCreate`, or unsubscribe in `onDestroyView`